# using webpack-stream & gulp does not transpile ES6 import

Tags: javascript, webpack, gulp, babeljs

I'm trying to use webpack with gulp and I'm getting this error in the browser console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

As webpack official documentation noted [here](https://webpack.github.io/docs/usage-with-gulp.html) I'm using webpack-stream with webpack.config.js. My gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return gulp.src('./src/js/index.js')
    .pipe(webpack(require('./webpack.config.js')))        
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./template/js/'));    
});
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
   rules: [{
     test: /\.js$/,
     exclude: /node_modules/,
     loader: 'babel-loader',
   }]
  },
};
```

index.js:

```
import sum from './sum';
console.log(sum(2,4));
```

and sum.js

```
const sum = (a,b) => {
   return a + b;
}
export default sum;
```

this is just a simple test to start the project boilerplate.
I also installed `babel-core`,`babel-loader` and `babel-preset-es2015` and I have the `.babelrc` file at the root of my project folder

.babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you using `bundle.js` in your web browser?

Comment: @Xotic750 yes, that's the reason I'm getting `Unexpected token import` error in the console

Comment: So when you look in your `bundle.js` (we can't see this content as it is not posted) is any transpiling happening?

Comment: @Xotic750 I can see webpack code at the top of `bundle.js` but no, there is no transpiling I think, because at the bottom I can see `import sum from './sum';`

Comment: Be sure to check that you meet all the requirements of [babel-loader](https://github.com/babel/babel-loader), we don't know what versions of libraries you are using in your project.

Comment: @Xotic750 `"babel-loader": "^7.1.0"` `"webpack-stream": "^3.2.0"` `"gulp": "^3.9.1"` `"babel-core": "^6.25.0"` `"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1"`

Comment: So `babel-loader` since v7 dropped support for `webpack` v1 but `webpack-stream` is using `webpack` v1 (it does not support anything other than v1)

Comment: @Xotic750 hmmm, that's odd. Maybe I should find another way to use webpack with gulp instead of `webpack-stream`. I`ll search with that goal in mind, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dependency version problem.

**babel-loader**

> v7.0.0 @danez danez released this on 21 Apr · 13 commits to master
>   since this release
>
> :boom: Breaking Change
>
> Drop support for node < 4
>
> Drop support for webpack 1

https://github.com/babel/babel-loader/releases/tag/v7.0.0

**webpack-stream**

> "dependencies": { "webpack": "^1.12.9" }

https://github.com/shama/webpack-stream/blob/master/package.json